# More than one UserDetailsService registered. Please use a specific Id reference in <remember-me/> <openid-login/> or <x509 /> elements

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am attempting to enable remember me functionality using spring security

```
<bean id="userService" class="mypath.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl" />

<security:http auto-config='true'>
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/Login" filters="none" />
  <security:form-login login-page='/Login' authentication-failure-url="/Login?login_error=1"/>
  <security:remember-me data-source-ref="dataSource" />
</security:http>
```

However, I seem to have specify the userService somewhere in the remember-me element ?  How do I do this.

The error I am getting on starting tomcat is

```
More than one UserDetailsService registered. 
Please use a specific Id reference in <remember-me/> <openid-login/> or <x509 /> elements.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok it wasn't that hard, just in case anyway else finds the spring documentation rather challenging to navigate:

```
<security:remember-me data-source-ref="dataSource" user-service-ref="myUserService"/>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.. made a duplicate service that was slightly different, and this was the key to fixing my broken build.